# How to check file extension in ionic 3 template

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

How can I check for a file extension using `IF` condition in ionic 3 template?

What I tried which returned error:

```
<img *ngIf='plan.media = jpg' src="{{ plan.media }}" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like:

.html

```
<img *ngIf="isImage(plan.media)" [src]="plan.media">
```

.ts

```
isImage(icon) {
    const ext = ['.jpg', '.jpeg', '.bmp', '.gif', '.png', '.svg'];
    return ext.some(el => icon.endsWith(el));
}
```

this will check these file extensions and return true if matched.